# Wordpress form entries store to external sql database

Tags: sql, wordpress

There is a WordPress web server. Users will be registered and pay through form (WP Form or any other).
I have an RDS SQL server running independently and I want the registration details and payments details to be inserted in to the RDS DB from the web server. All is on AWS LightSail.
I hope it's clear now.
Thank you.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Is the question not clear? Anybody? any ideas?